# Centre map on marker click in CartoDB

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

How do I centre my map after clicking on a marker in carto js? I'm using createLayer but not sure where my listener should be applied (i.e. to map object created using Leaflet or within createLayer call).

Comment: The listener should be applied to the featureclick within the createLayer done call, and use the Leaflet center map functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jags have commented, you have to apply a `featureclick` to the listener and then you can use `getBounds` method to get the bbox (or marker position) from the selected feature and finally set the view and zoom according to the output parameters:

```
sublayer.on('featureClick', function(e, pos, latlng, data) {

  // get cartodb_id from selected feature
  var id_selected = data.cartodb_id;
  console.log(id_selected);

  // get bounds from selected feature
  var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'ramirocartodb'});
  sql.getBounds(
    query + " where cartodb_id = {{cartodb_id}}", 
    {cartodb_id: id_selected})
  .done(function(bounds) {
    console.log(bounds);
    $('#bbox-top').text(bounds[0]);
    $('#bbox-buttom').text(bounds[1]);

    // zoom to selected feature
    let newLat = (bounds[0][0]+bounds[1][0])*0.50, newLong = (bounds[0][1]+bounds[1][1])*0.50;
    map.setView([newLat, newLong],10,true);
  });
});
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/bcf8dbd69fc723e30a6eec7ce35b5b7d) you have a working example.